# Why Github workflows doesn't recognize command?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, cd

I built a github workflow and for some reason it doesn't recognize the dita.bat file as a command. All the files are present in the repo and checkout is performed.

Error:

```
ant
ant.bat
dita
dita.bat
sudo: ./dita.bat: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Github workflow step:

```
- name: Build WebHelp Responsive
    run: |
        cd oxygen-publishing-engine-3.x/bin
        ls
        sudo ./dita.bat --input=../../doc/project-documentation/search-service- 
        doc.ditamap --format=webhelp-responsive - 
        Dwebhelp.publishing.template=../../templates/webhelp-documentation-template -- 
        output=../../doc/project-documentation/out
```

Comment: Please try `chmod +x chmod +x` before calling your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `chmod +x filename` before calling your script.